# Mobile numeric keyboard [0-9] in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, keyboard

Is it possible to open up the mobile numeric keyboard in a textarea box?

The typical `pattern="[0-9]*"` does not seem to work with a textarea and I can't find any other information on this anywhere else. I am trying to get this working in an angular app, so is there some way to preventDefault() on the default keyboard and somehow trigger the numeric keyboard?

e.g.

```
<textarea id="searchBox" pattern="[0-9]*" ng-model="searchParams.searchString" rows="3" ng-blur="formatSearch()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible for `textarea`. I have searched exhaustively on this and tried many varietions of pattern and types and so on but it just is not supported for `textarea`.

There are two possible solutions, either you can create your own html5 custom soft keyboard and apply a trick not to open the default keyboard.

Or (more elegant I think) use a normal input with type `number` or type `tel` and attach an onkeyup listerer. When enter is pressed, you process the line into your textarea and clean plus refocus the input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a shame we can't use the numeric keyboard with textarea. I will try to figure out a different approach for this. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

isn't possible use input?
like

```
<input name="numbers" type="tel">
```

and than style the input like a textarea.
i dont have any idea for the textarea.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this isn't an option for what we need. We need a multi-line text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global attribute inputmode in textarea to alter Android or iPhone keypad.

`<textarea inputmode="numeric"></textarea>`

MDN Web Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Answer (score -1):

A textarea can be validated via php but not in html. Below is my way of validating textarea,

```
$value=$_POST['value from textarea']
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $value != 1) {
    echo"oops";
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```